# Start Spring Integration route on demand, not during context initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a Spring Integration route (made via DSL) that polls the files from a specific folder (as shown in [Polling from file using Java DSL - compile error when adding Files.inboundAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524793/polling-from-file-using-java-dsl-compile-error-when-adding-files-inboundadapte)) and sends to Rabbit.

When I configured the flow as explained in the link above, it starts on configuration stage already. I, however, would like to start it in runtime, later, since I need to connect to Rabbit first.

How can I configure IntegrationFlow to be started/stopped later on demand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `autoStartup(false)`.

```
e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000))
      .autoStartup(false)
```

then `flow.start()` when you are ready.