# Spring integration - passing data between flows

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a special IntegrationFlow configured like

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow setupRabbitFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(myInputChannel)     
            .handle((p, h) -> rabbitPublisher.publishToRabbit(p, h))
            .get();
}
```

and some other flow that processes incoming data from some XML files, e.g. as shown here [Polling from file using Java DSL - compile error when adding Files.inboundAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524793/polling-from-file-using-java-dsl-compile-error-when-adding-files-inboundadapte). By the end of that flow I want to pass Message to the abovementioned rabbit-sending "sink". How do I declare this?

Comment: Just a quickie: method name becomes bean name if qualifier is not defined. You probably don't want Spring component with name "setupRabbitFlow".

Comment: I think he is fine with that logical name for the `IntegrationFlow` bean: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the first class citizen in Spring Integration is a [MessageChannel](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessageChannel.html) abstraction.

Any interaction between Spring Integration components (endpoints) is really done through the message channels.

What you need from your second flow is just specify `.channel(myInputChannel)` in the end of that flow. And the result of the XML processing will be send to your first flow.